# How to get all the tables under the table space in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, create-table

I have a requirement to get all the tables in specific table-space  in mysql.

I have created a tablespace & tables under the tablespace like below.

```
CREATE TABLESPACE attendence
       ADD DATAFILE 'attendence.ibd'
       ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLESPACE players
       ADD DATAFILE 'players.ibd'
       ENGINE=INNODB;

 CREATE TABLE student (id  INT PRIMARY KEY, name varchar(50))
        TABLESPACE attendence COMMENT 'student table'

 CREATE TABLE Librarian(id  INT PRIMARY KEY, name varchar(50))
        TABLESPACE attendence COMMENT 'Librarian table'

 CREATE TABLE Players(id  INT PRIMARY KEY, name varchar(50))
        TABLESPACE Players COMMENT 'Players in the college '
```

Now I want to query like get the tables full description of columns based on the table space. Let's say I want tables under the `Players` tablespace I want only `'Players'` table.

This is for all the tables under the particular db

```
select * from information_schema.tables where TABLE_SCHEMA='springbootdb'
```

but I need only tables under the table space.

Can  anyone tell me I can achieve this?

Comment: What's a table space?

Comment: What database are you using - `sql-server` or `mysql`?

Comment: @StormoPL I need to use both , right now  i am trying for the mysql

Comment: then you should state that in the question

Comment: Your teacher is giving you a dumb assignment.  MySQL happily chugged along for 2 decades without `CREATE TABLESPACE`.  Only in 5.7 did that statement come into existence.  I dare say that 99.9% of MySQL users have _never_ used `CREATE TABLESPACE` and most of them never will.  So, why waste any time on it??

Comment: It is not related to database-design. Please remove the TAG.

Comment: If this is MySQL, why do I see SQL Server tag on the question?????  Please tag properly!!!!!

Comment: Also this is not Oracle.  You don't need tablespace.

Comment: @cva - I have been using MySQL for 19 years; I have never created a tablespace.  I can think of 2 minor uses for such; neither has been important in any project I have been involved in.

Comment: @cva - In older versions, `INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES` was the table to look in.  But then, `ibdata1` was the default tablespace, and each `.ibd` file was a tablespace.  (Think `innodb_file_per_table`.)  But a MySQL developer never needed to know that.

Comment: @cva - On my server (with lots of databases and tables), `FILES` is empty.  (But then, I am using 5.6, which does not have `CREATE TABLESPACE`.)

Comment: Have you tried `SHOW TABLES;`  See [SHOW TABLES Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-tables.html)